# How to convert current datetime into 13 digits Unix timestamp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I want to convert current datetime into Unix time stamp

**My Code**

```
import time
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime.now()
unixtime = time.mktime(d.timetuple())

print(unixtime)
```

**My output:**

```
1577098747.0
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1577098747123.0
```

Above code gives me timestamp upto 10 digits but I want it to be accurate till 13 digits.

*Note: I don't want to convert it manually multiplying by `10**3` I want to capture accurate milliseconds.*

Comment: you can use time.time() function

Comment: Your requirement is incorrect. What you have *is* a Unix timestamp (seconds since epoch); you seem to instead want milliseconds since the epoch. Neither of these have a specific number of digits, though obviously times around the current will have the expected number of digits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

do it like this

```
import time
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime.now()
unixtime = datetime.datetime.timestamp(d)*1000

print(unixtime)
```

or you just use `time.time()`